# IBM Integration Toolkit Issue for Validation

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I am working on IBM Integration toolkit. I wanted to understand the exact validation feature of a particular input node via an example. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Validation on inputs node you can see them in validation tab, you can choose how to validate (`content`, `conent and value` or `none` if you like to implement your own vaildation and what to do if this validate is failure (`Exception` , `Exception List` , `user trace`, `log local error`),

validation done automatically depends on the `message parser` : `[BLOB, XMLNSC, XMLNS, SOAP, MRM, ..etc ]`, and `message structure`which is defined in your `message set`.

**for example :**
If you create a `message set` with `message definition` file and this `message definition` has got and element and this element is `required` and `integer`, and you set this `message set` to your input node, validation feature runs automatically if you put for example `string` value or you left it empty validation exception occurs.

[image]